# undefined reference error

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

i got undefined reference error from my main function, but i can not find the problem.
my files are:

```
//Student.h
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Student{
public:
 Student(std::string &line);
...
virtual void evaluateValue(){}
 virtual ~Student(){}
....
};
#endif

//HeStudent.h
#ifndef HESTUDENT_H
#define HESTUDENT_H
#include "Student.h"

class HeStudent : public Student{
public:
 HeStudent(std::string line) : Student(line){
  ...
 }

 static int AgradesCount;
 static double Aaverage;

 virtual void evaluateValue();
 virtual ~HeStudent(){}

};
#endif
```

for each .h file there is his .cpp file.
i've got also a main.cpp file which contains the main and in the main i create:
Student stud = new HeStudent(line);
i don't know if it's necessary but i included the Student.h and the HeStudent.h
and i get some long error and it said:

```
HeStudent::HeStudent(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)]+0x22): undefined reference to `Student::Student
```

can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

A guess: The constructor of your class `HeStudent` calls the constructor of the base class `Student`:

```
class HeStudent : public Student{
public:
 HeStudent(std::string line) : Student(line){
 //                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 //                          call to ctor of base class
 ...
```

However, at least in the code you've shown us, that base constructor is not actually defined:

```
class Student{
public:
 Student(std::string &line);
 ...                    // ^
                        // do you have a definition of the ctor's body somewhere?
```

Note the semicolon at the end of this line. Have you defined the constructor's body elsewhere or is it missing? In the latter case, that might explain your compilation error.

---

**Update:** Another guess then.

```
class Student{
public:
 Student(std::string &line);
 ...            //   ^
                // could this cause the problem?
```

Comment: as i said, each .h file has it's .cpp file with the implementation

Answer (score 2):

Are you compiling each .cpp files and not just the main.cpp ? If not, it is a linker problem:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c student.cpp
g++ -c hestudent.cpp 
g++ main.o student.o hestudent.o
```

Comment: Yes, i am compiling each .cpp file

Comment: but as i mentioned, the implementation is in the .cpp files

Answer (score 2):

Where are you putting the definition of your constructor:

```
Student(std::string &line);
```

I don't see it, and if it's missing, then that is at least one problem you have.  You'll notice that you have `{}` after each of your other declarations which is also defining them.  You constructor has no such curly brackets thus you must define the constructor somewhere else.  (likely in a Student.cpp file)

You haven't shown the Student.cpp file, so you may think you have it defined and you don't.  Make sure you have the `Student(std::string &line)` defined as:

```
Student::Student(std::string &line)
{
   // Any specific code you need here
}
```

Comment: Can you test whether or not you can create a student directly?  Also, just as a suggestion, your Student constructor should be Student(const std::string &line) unless for some reason you need/want the Student constructor to change the line passed by the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i found my problem, in the Student.cpp file i inline the constructor.
did i changed the signature of the constructor when adding inline? why it fix my problem?

Comment: From the C++ FAQ on inline functions: Note: It's imperative that the function's definition (the part between the {...}) be placed in a header file, unless the function is used only in a single .cpp file. In particular, if you put the inline function's definition into a .cpp file and you call it from some other .cpp file, you'll get an "unresolved external" error from the linker.